# Plain string template query for elasticsearch through java API?

Tags: java, templates, elasticsearch

I have a template foo.mustache saved in {{ES_HOME}}/config/scripts.

POST to http://localhost:9200/forward/_search/template with the following `message body` returns a valid response:

```
{
  "template": {
    "file": "foo"
  },
  "params": {
    "q": "a",
    "hasfilters": false
  }
}
```

I want to translate this to using the java API now that I've validated all the different components work. The documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-template.html) describes how to do it in java:

```
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("forward")
        .setTemplateName("foo")
        .setTemplateType(ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE)
        .setTemplateParams(template_params)
        .get();
```

However, I would instead like to just send a plain string query (i.e. the contents of the message body from above) rather than build up the response using the java. Is there a way to do this? I know with normal queries, I can construct it like so:

```
SearchRequestBuilder response = client.prepareSearch("forward")
    .setQuery("""JSON_QUERY_HERE""")
```

I believe the setQuery() method wraps the contents into a query object, which is not what I want for my template query. If this is not possible, I will just have to go with the documented way and convert my json params to `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just translating my template_params to a `Map<String, Object>` as the documentation requires. I utilized groovy's JsonSlurper to convert the text to an object with a pretty simple method.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


public static Map<String,Object> convertJsonToTemplateParam(String s) {
    Object result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(s);
    //Manipulate your result if you need to do any additional work here.
    //I.e. Programmatically determine value of hasfilters if filters != null
    return (Map<String,Object>) result;
}
```

And you could pass in the following as a string to this method:

```
{
    "q": "a",
    "hasfilters": true
    "filters":[
       {
        "filter_name" : "foo.untouched",
        "filters" : [ "FOO", "BAR"]
       },
       {
        "filter_name" : "hello.untouched",
        "list" : [ "WORLD"]
       }
     ]
}
```